# Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid

Tags: linq-to-sql, string, integer

When I try to run the following code I get a Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid. error.

```
        Dim maj = (From c In connect.Courses _
                  Where c.COTRequired = CBool("True") _
                  Select c.CourseID, c.CourseName, c.CreditHours).Except _
                  (From en In connect.Enrollments _
                   Join s In connect.Sections On en.SectionID Equals s.SectionID _
                   Join cs In connect.Courses On s.CourseID Equals cs.CourseID _
                   Join st In connect.Students On en.StudentID Equals st.StudentID _
                   Order By cs.CourseName _
                   Where st.StudentID = CInt(SID) _
                   Select cs.CourseID, cs.CourseName, cs.CreditHours)

        Dim maj2 = (From m2 In maj _
                    Select m2.CreditHours).Sum().ToString
```

**Here is the error detail.  I know there is some type of conversion that needs to take place, but am having trouble pinning down exactly which one.**

System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
  Message="Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid."
  Source="System.Data.Linq"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInvocation(InvocationExpression invoke)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.Visit(Expression node)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitExpression(Expression exp)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitBinary(BinaryExpression b)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.Visit(Expression node)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitExpression(Expression exp)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitWhere(Expression sequence, LambdaExpression predicate)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.Visit(Expression node)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSelect(Expression sequence, LambdaExpression selector)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.Visit(Expression node)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitExcept(Expression source1, Expression source2)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitSequenceOperatorCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression mc)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.VisitInner(Expression node)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.QueryConverter.ConvertOuter(Expression node)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.BuildQuery(Expression query, SqlNodeAnnotations annotations)
       at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
       at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at System.Data.Linq.Provider.BindingList.Create[T](DataContext context, IEnumerable`1 sequence)
       at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.GetNewBindingList()
       at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.ComponentModel.IListSource.GetList()
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListBindingHelper.GetList(Object list)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListBindingHelper.GetList(Object dataSource, String dataMember)
       at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.ResetList()
       at System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource.set_DataSource(Object value)
       at WindowsApplication1.Form1.ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Charles.McBeth\Documents\School\ProgramManagement\Final Project\Final Project\Final Project\Form1.vb:line 68
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.set_SelectedIndex(Int32 value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.RefreshItems()
       at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnDataSourceChanged(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.SetDataConnection(Object newDataSource, BindingMemberInfo newDisplayMember, Boolean force)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ListControl.set_DataSource(Object value)
  InnerException: System.FormatException
       Message="Input string was not in a correct format."
       Source="Microsoft.VisualBasic"
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ParseDouble(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat)
            at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToInteger(String Value)
       InnerException:

Comment: Update your earlier question: don't ask a new question for the same problem.

Comment: Retagged linqtosql to linq-to-sql as it has more hits.

Comment: tvanfosson, this is not the same question as earlier.  It is another question in a different area of the same code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it's this bit:

```
st.StudentID = CInt(SID)
```

What is SID, and is there a possibility that it's an empty string? What do you want the code to do if it *is* an empty string?

Comment: You are correct. SID is an empty string.  I had the code in a spot that was trying to use the variable before it was set.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The only explicit conversion to integer I can see is `CInt(SID)` - what type is the `SID` field? If it contains alphanumeric values, that might be your culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I find LINQ to SQL's limitations intolerable, so I developed my own data foundation layer.  However I have found that when I needed to use LINQ to SQL it helped to hoist all calculations out of the code.

In your case I would try:

```
Dim intSID = CInt(SID)
Dim maj = ...
        Where c.COTRequired = True _
        ...
        Where st.StudentID = intSID _
        ...
```

Note that VB.NET has the constants True and False (no quotes) that are actual boolean values.